# Where do I buy a code signing certificate I can just download and not get on a USB drive?

Tags: windows, code-signing

I'm trying to get a new certificate for my open source SQL desktop app.

Previously I just downloaded the certificate from Sectigo.

Now all the certificate authorities want to ship me a physical drive with the certificate on it. This is crazy!

My certificate expires in 3 weeks and I'm going away on vacation in a week. I can't believe there's no way to do this entirely online.

My app provides a small, but important, revenue stream for me, I can't afford to have my binaries unsigned.

Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Use of FIPS140-2 or EAL4+ hardware is now REQUIRED for code-signing](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/changes-coming-to-ov-code-signing-certificates-keys-starting-nov-15/) (the USB is not just a 'drive' i.e. a storage device, it does the actual cryptographic operations)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Certum. https://shop.certum.eu/data-safety/code-signing-certificates.html

They offer code signing certificates for open source projects which can be signed via the cloud which works as a virtual card.

And a helpful blog post here: https://blog.inkdrop.app/code-signing-certificate-for-indie-developers-564f86492957